# What is the pattern in this set of numbers?

Tags: pattern-recognition

$[3,6,11,18,27,38,...]$.
I need to write this set in set-builder notation but I can't find any pattern, I see no common multiple, it doesn't appear to be a geometric or arithmetic series. The problem comes from the book of proof.

Comment: Look at their differences. ​ ​

Comment: http://oeis.org is your friend

Comment: Given only six integers, it's quite a leap to find a pattern based on only six integers, to apply to countably infinitely many integers. Given the six integers you include, we have a difference of 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, ...

Comment: differences 3,5,7,9......

Comment: subtract $2$ from each term.

Comment: $$A=\{x\in\mathbb{N}|x=n^2 + 2,\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\land n>0\}$$

Comment: In general the answer to "what is the next number in this sequence" is "anything you want it to be", unless you put some constraint on the nature of the generating function. But $n^2+2$ is probably the simplest answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like $f(k)=k^2+2$  .

Comment: $x \in \{k^2 + 2 \, | k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\}$  See [this](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C6%2C11%2C18%2C27%2C38%2C&language=english&go=Search)